# Firestore crashing with MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Starting today Firestore crashing with the below error. I have no clue what this is about. Can someone from Firebase team help?

```
{ 
 Error: Cannot find module 'google-gax' 
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15) 
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25) 
 at Module.require (module.js:597:17) 
 at require (internal/module.js:11:18) 
 at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js:16:13) 
 at Module._compile (module.js:653:30) 
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10) 
 at Module.load (module.js:566:32) 
 at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12) 
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' 
}
```

It's a simple cloud function where I'm using firestore database. I'm using firebase admin SDK on Node.js platform.

Comment: just install https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-gax

Comment: Did that but it didn't work!

Comment: Solved it by downgrading firebase admin from 8.0.0 to 7.4.0

Comment: Solved this by just re-running `npm i`. Seems installing @google-cloud/firestore (I'm using 3.8.4) didn't install this dependency